# ANSI C - Input of a numeric matrix

Tags: c, input, matrix

I have to implement a C program that performs the multiplication of two matrices (yeah, homework :), and I'm trying to devise a function that receives the input from the user and validates it.

My initial thought was: let's only ask the user to enter the matrices (numbers separated by whitespace, rows by newlines, and maybe a 'e' by itself after a newline to signal the matrices' end), so that the program will automatically calculate the number of columns and rows and store them in a two-dimensional array.. however, how can I dynamically allocate enough memory for them if I don't know their sizes beforehand? If possibile, I'd avoid asking the user to manually input the number of rows and columns of each matrix.

Moreover, what's the best way to validate the input against wrong and/or missing data (e.g. letters, garbage, rows with less numbers than the others, etc?). I was thinking about strtok'ing each row, splitting them using whitespaces as delimiters, and checking if each token is strictly numeric. Is this the best way to determine if each row only contains valid numerical values? Is there a more clean and sane approach?

This is my pseudocode:

```
function getMatrix () {
   while(true) {
   Receive a matrix as input, until the user enters 'e' in a new line by itself;
   Split the matrix in rows delimited by newlines;
   Split the rows in strings delimited by whitespaces;
   For each string {
     If the string is numeric, save it as matrix[rowNumber][colNumber];
     Else print a warning and discard the entire input;
   }
   If each row of the matrix has an equal number of elements {
      return the matrix as an array of integers;
   } else {
      print a warning and let the user re-enter the data.
  }
 }
}

main () {
    matrix1 = getMatrix;
    matrix2 = getMatrix;

    matrix1x2 = multiply the two matrices (this is the easy part :)
    print matrix1x2.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit cumbersome in C. But if you don't want the user to specify the dimensions of the matrix, you will need a growing buffer to put the numbers in. You can implement this using realloc. It would go something like this (not tested):

```
int n = 0, nmax = 100;
size_t len = 0;
int nrow = 0, ncol = 0;
double * mat = malloc(nmax);
char * line = NULL, *tok;
while(getline(&line, &len, stdin) > 0)
{
    nrow++;
    ncol = 0;
    for(tok = strtok(line, " \t"); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, " \t"))
    {
        ncol++; n++;
        if(n > nmax) mat = realloc(mat, (nmax *= 2)*sizeof(double));
        mat[n-1] = atof(tok);
    }
}
mat = realloc(mat, nrol*nrow*sizeof(double));
free(line);
```

What this is doing is to read input linewise, loop over space or tab-separated tokens, converts each to a double, and assigns it to a one-dimensional buffer, which is expanded as needed. I multiply its capacity by two each time, in order to minimize the time spent on reallocating memory (this is what the C++ vector class does too). It also keeps track of the number of rows and columns seen, but does not do any error checking so a practical version would need a bit more work.

To get the value at index (i,j) of the resulting matrix, you have to calculate a linear index: `val = mat[i*ncol+j]`.